# AcroPDFLib to open PDF file from stream in WindowsForms C# .NET

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, stream

I've spent the whole afternoon looking for an answer to my question and found none :(

I'm making a windows forms application and one of it's features is to show files stored in a DB.
This files, upon upload, can be marked as "read-only", meaning they cannot be downloaded.
At this point, I'm struggling with PDF files. I'm using the AcroPDFLib and I can't find a way to display the file from the byte array stored in the DB.

So, my question is, is there a way to open a PDF file from a stream?
Even if it's a plugin, what plugin is that and where can I find it?

Using the web browser object, I don't think it will work since I would have to create something server-side that sends to the response output the stream.
And creating the file in a temporary folder... well, in that case I might as well allow the file download :D

Thanks for your help

Comment: You have stored PDF file as Bytes right...?

Comment: Yes. And in the DB is as Varbinary.

Comment: Any third-party control or something, as long it's free, I'm ok with it :) just can't find any :(

Comment: Good news: there's [MuPDF](http://www.mupdf.com/), which seems to do what you want, and its [wrapper for .NET](https://code.google.com/p/mupdf-converter/). Bad news: I've been spending last two hours to make a small sample, but failed. Will certainly be fighting it tomorrow, but I suggest you to play with it, maybe you are luckier than me!

Comment: Nice :) Thanks for your help, I'll give it a try a bit later, at this point I decided to go with the workaround (using the webbrowser) so that I can show some work done... the life of a developer... Then I'll look into it to make this right :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to do what you want, you need to open the file from a memory stream, however from the [Interapplication Communication API reference from Adobe](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/iac_api_reference.pdf) we get that there is only one Open(...) method:

> **Syntax:**
>  VARIANT_BOOL Open(BSTR szFullPath, BSTR szTempTitle);
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> szFullPath
>  The full path of the file to open.
>
> szTempTitle
>  An optional title for the window in which the file is
>   opened. If szTempTitle is NULL or the empty string, it is ignored.
>   Otherwise, szTempTitle is used as the window title.

So I would *guess* that what you are trying to do cannot be done with Adobe's library.

Comment: +1 for digging the API and pretty much answer the it's possible question :)